# Does Kotlin optimize sum() for ranges and progressions?

Tags: kotlin, sum

What happens under the hood, when you call `IntProgression.sum()`?

Sample code:

```
val n: Int
val sum = (0..n).sum()
```

1. does Kotlin iterate all elements from 0 to `n`?

   ```
   // O(n)
   var sum = 0
   for (i in 0..n) {
       sum += i
   }
   ```
2. or does it use a formula for calculating the sum of arithmetic sequence? which I assume is more performant for large values of `n`.

   ```
   // O(1)
   var sum = (0 + n) * (n + 1) / 2
   ```

Comment: You can find out yourself by making n progressively larger and seeing if it takes longer to compute.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk But that will, at best, only tell you an implementation detail, it won't say anything about specified behavior.

Comment: You can Ctrl+click a function call in the IDE to jump to the source code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 While that's worth knowing, I think mu's comment applies there, too :-)  Implementations can and do change over time; only what's in the official documentation is guaranteed.

Comment: @gidds the OP’s question is literally asking what the implementation is. I was just pointing out they could have instantly answered this for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Kotlin does not optimize the `sum()`.

The function is an extension function on `Iterable` (`IntProgression` implements `Iterable<Int>`). That function *could* implement different sum algorithms depending on the actual type, but it just loops over all elements of the Iterable:

```
var sum: Int = 0
for (element in this) {
    sum += element
}
return sum
```